# Implementing Active Record Caching in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-4

Any how can I implement Codeigniter Active Record Caching (https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#caching) in Laravel 4?

Comment: People prefer for you to show stuff you've already tried

Comment: sorry, forgot to add the question mark at title

Answer (score 0):

You cannot implement **Codeigniter** caching in **Laravel 4**.

But you can implement **Laravel** caching in **Laravel 4**. [Please see the caching docs here](http://laravel.com/docs/cache). There is also [specific docs for caching queries here](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#caching-queries). But in principle you do

```
$users = DB::table('users')->remember(10)->get();
```

Where 10 is the number of minutes to cache the result for.

Comment: what i want is to cache the query string itself, so i can continue the query part later; not cache the result..